# How to change the currency symbol for any one specific locale?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl, el

I'm using jstl to display a currency value like so...

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${sellingPrice}" type="currency"/>
```

which works 99% of the time.  Now I have a requirement that for a given locale, the customer does not want to show ANY currency symbol at all.

I tried this:

```
<fmt:formatNumber currencySymbol="" value="${sellingPrice}" type="currency"/>
```

...removes the currency symbols no matter what the locale is.

and I thought about using spring message like this:

```
<fmt:formatNumber currencySymbol="<spring:message code='myCurrency.symbol' />" value="${sellingPrice}" type="currency"/>
```

but the problem is then I'd need to go back and create the correct currency symbol for all the other locales I support as well as adding that spring message for any new locales that may come up...

What I really need is to be able to say something like:

`if(locale == 'EN_XX') {
    currencySymbol=' ';
} else {
 // otherwise use whatever the normal currency symbol would be for that locale
}`

Is there any way to override the default currency symbol for a specific locale at a lower level than the JSP?  I mean the value has to come from somewhere right?

Comment: Can locale property files http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization work for you?

Comment: @varren I'm using: `<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">` and I already have a localeResolver defined...not seeing how I could change the currency symbol in that for a specific locale though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own custom tag that extends FormatNumberTag.  It figures out the correct Locale and then calls the FormatNumberTag.setCurrencySymbol("...");

```
public class MyFormatNumberTag extends FormatNumberTag {

   public MyFormatNumberTag() {
       super();
   }

   //...snip...

   @Override
   public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
       Locale locale = getMyRequestLocale();

       if(locale == Locale.EN_GB) setCurrencySymbol("");

       return super.doStartTag();
   }
}
```

Hope this helps someone.